# Html input type date losing value on onfocusout

Tags: javascript, html

I have this `input` `type="date"`:

```html
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Mandatory field" id="MyInput" name="MyInput" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.type='text'}" onfocus="(this.type='date')" type="text" value="01/05/2022">
```

it works fine, but I dont know why it looses the value on focusout. How can I fix this? It shouldn't loose the value on focusout.

[image: This is what happens.]

Comment: Converted your code to a snippet and it seems to work fine as-is  **edit** when selecting a date - if **a date is not selected** it is cleared as noted in the below answer - this scenario was not well described in the question

Answer (score 1):

Start with `type=date` and set the value like so. I guess it cant convert the initial text to a date when you switch the type since its not in the correct format. It expects a date like this `YYYY-MM-DD` however you provide `01-05-2022` -> `MM-DD-YYYY`. I assume thats why the value is lost.

```html
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Mandatory field" id="MyInput" name="MyInput" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.type='text'}" onfocus="(this.type='date')" type="date" value="2022-01-05">
```

Comment: Changing to `value="2022-01-05"` seems to be the fix, no need to start with type=date

Comment: I understand, but the date format should be "DD/MM/YYYY"

Comment: I will be displayed in that way. However the correct way to provide the date is the format in my answer. When you put in in a text field however it will not be displayed correctly. For me i cant write text in the input since it changes to a date when i click it or is that the issue? If so you will need to process the string into the format `YYYY-MM-DD` before you swap the input type

Comment: @freedomn-m I switched it to the date type initially is that the order is correct. If not the year will actually come first

Comment: The `input` `value=` must be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.   The *displayed* format (when type='date') is determined by your browser's locale.  When you *read* the value (via code) it will be a string "yyyy-mm-dd" which you (may) need to convert to a date object.   As far as the *end user* is concerned, it's always in the correct format while it's `type='date'` - the issue is that it's `type='text'` initially (for whatever reason).  I suggest leaving it as type='date' all the time, then the user can actually click on the date picker without having to click twice (ie, better UX).

Comment: Otherwise you'll just need a bit more js - on focus take the value mm/dd/yyyy format and convert it to yyyy/mm/dd - and reverse on focus out / blur